# Compile Component in Ember 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ember.js

I have a component in Ember2 that receives a parameter `{{my-component product=p}}`. I need to pre compile the component and get the generated html.

I have tried to use `ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile` but without success. `let template = hbs"{{mycomponent product=p }}`;

Comment: Why do you wanna do this? Can you explain your use-case? Ember is not build for pre-rendering. But maybe fastboot is what you want.

Comment: I am using google maps and I need to pass the content (html string) to a infobox to render a beautiful infobox. I have created a component for that and now I would like to compile that component, generate the html and pass as parameter of infobox.

Comment: I may misunderstand but can you clarify: you have a string (html) and you want to put it in a component? Then use `{{{mystring}}}`. With 3 curly.

Answer (score 0):

First its important to clarify the terms. *Compiling* a component does *not* mean to produce HTML! It basically means to produce a bytecode that can be used with the glimmer runtime to produce and update *DOM*. Ember will *never* produce HTML, and this is important to understand.

If you think ember produces HTML and then gives that to the browser to render you are wrong.

Ember directly produces DOM, and then keeps track of the DOM nodes to update the DOM and allow live binding.

So basically there is *no* public API in ember to do what you want.
Of course you can just render the component, and use `this.element.outerHTML` to access the HTML. But remember that with that you will lose *all* ember functionality like live-binding or actions.

This is especially tricky because google maps renders all into an iframe.

[ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole) shows that its possible to render ember content outside the main div, but they make use of private API and I think this possibility ends with the iframe.

Comment: Which public API? 

I just want to call something similar to: `Ember.Handlebars.Compile('{{component}}', {product: p})` and have `<p>Product Name</p>`

Comment: The only way is to render the component and use `this.element.outerHTML`. Everything else is private.

Comment: But i dont have access to `this.element.outerHTML` inside the controller... I have to think another solution :/

Comment: Yes. There is no way to produce HTML. You can produce DOM, and then use the DOM to produce html, however there is no public API to tell ember to render a component and return DOM. Except the visit api, but this won't help you. Honestly I would use a simple template string for your use-case.